# Dropwizard - jax-rs Response with string as entity is returning expected 'u' instead of 'e'

Tags: java, jax-rs, dropwizard

I have the following endpoint in my code :

```
@GET
@UnitOfWork
@Timed
@Path("/create")
public Response register(@QueryParam("name") String name,
                         @QueryParam("password") String password) {

    // Bcrypt encryption for password
    String encr = enc.encrypt(password);

    // Create a new user object to use with DAO.
    User newUser = new User(name, encr);

    // Save the user to the database and return a string which represents the ID.
    String res = "newID : " + _userDAO.createUser(newUser);

    // Return the string inside a response.
    return Response.status(201).entity(res).build();
}
```

The Bcrypt works, and the User does get added to the DB - I also get a valid ID back in the "res" string. This error I would assume is either with the formatting of the res string, or in how I am building the response - but I keep getting the following result when I call this via a rest client :

```
Expected 'u' instead of 'e'
```

Sometimes the u and e characters will change, but the main point of the error is the same.

This class is annotated to produce JSON - maybe that has something to do with this?

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your line

```
return Response.status(201).entity(res).build();
```

you set the entity of the response to be a String (because "res" is a String). 
And your String is "newID : <...>". You are building a malformed json string since the json brackets are missing. Correct would be "{newID : <...>}"

But you should not build your json string yourself. Dropwizard should do this for you.

You need to put your "res" into an object. Something like this:

```
public class RegistrationResponse {
    public int newID;

    public RegistrationResponse(int newID) {
      this.newID = newID;
    }
}

@GET
@UnitOfWork
@Timed
@Path("/create")
public RegistrationResponse register(@QueryParam("name") String name,
                     @QueryParam("password") String password) {

  String encr = enc.encrypt(password);

  User newUser = new User(name, encr);

  int newID = _userDAO.createUser(newUser);

  return new RegistrationResponse(newID);
}
```